# In Yocto, Linux kernel configuration is not accepting the configuration from meta layer

Tags: yocto, yocto-recipe, yocto-layer

I have written a panel driver and now converted into a meta layer. I have created the meta layer using devtool and configuration is stored in xxx-fragment.cfg

In xxx-fragment.cfg file, I set the config CONFIG_xxxx to Y i.e.
*CONFIG_xxxx=Y*

Unfortunately, I get the following error. Could someone kindly point me reason for the error?

```
WARNING: linux-imx-5.10.35+abcbdcbc-.4 do_kernel_configcheck: [kernel config]: specified values did not make it into the kernel's final configuration:

    [NOTE]: 'CONFIG_xxxx' last val (y) and .config val (n) do not match
    [INFO]: CONFIG_xxxx : n ## .config: 4363 :configs//./xxx-fragment.cfg (y) 
    [INFO]: raw config text:

        config CONFIG_xxxx
            tristate "xxxx"
            depends on OF && DRM_MIPI_DSI && DRM && DRM_PANEL && HAS_IOMEM
            help
              Say Y here if you want to enable support for xxxxxxx

        Config 'CONFIG_xxxx' has the following Direct dependencies (CONFIG_xxxx=y):
                OF(=y) && DRM_MIPI_DSI(=y) && DRM(=y) && DRM_PANEL(=y) && HAS_IOMEM(=y)
        Parent dependencies are:
             OF [y] DRM [y] DRM_PANEL [y] HAS_IOMEM [y] DRM_MIPI_DSI [y]
```